# Flutter expand Container to fill remaining space of Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have one image in a row and a text next to that image. I want the row to expand fully and image takes as its size, then remain full area should be taken by Container.

Here is my code snippet:

```
Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 50, 10, 8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(100, 0, 0, 0),
                  blurRadius: 5,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/card.png',
                    height: 62,
                    width: 62,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )
                ]),
                Container(
                  child: Text("Hello world"),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

I want it like this:
[image: Flutter UI]

Comment: You might want to use `ListTile` instead. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I recommend you to start building layouts only with `Row` and `Column` not to get confusing. I often build layouts as follows.

1. Layout objects(eg. Text, Image) only with `Row` and `Column`. And Set `mainAxisAlignment` and `crossAxisAlignment` property in `Row` and `Column`.
2. Set styles with `Padding` or `Align`, `Expanded` etc. You can also use `Container`.
3. Decorate in addition.

**Reference:**

**Layout basic:**

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout

**Tips when building layouts:**

https://medium.com/@liewjuntung/tips-on-using-android-studio-to-develop-flutter-apps-9e42c047b7f4

I hope you this will help you.

example code:

```
    Widget buildCard() {
      return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Color.fromARGB(100, 0, 0, 0),
              blurRadius: 5,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              'assets/card.png',
              height: 62,
              width: 62,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0, left: 12.0),
              child: Text(
                "Hello world",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  letterSpacing: 0.8,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Expanded instead of the Container around the Text.

Answer (score 0):

Give the container `alignment: Alignment.center`